# Reversing a binary string with a restricted Turing Machine

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle, algorithm, computer-science

Some malevolent entity (me) asks you to construct a [Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Description) which, given an input on its tape of the form $LbR$ where $b$ is some binary string, changes this to $Lb^{-1}R$ then halts (where $b^{-1}$ signifies $b$ in reverse order).

For example, given input $L001R$, after the machine halts the tape should be $L100R$

The catch: you only have precisely the input space to use for the computation: i.e., the head of the Turing machine may not move left of the endpoint $L$ nor right of $R$, nor may it write over $L$ or $R$ (it may however move onto them and read them as it would any other letter in its alphabet). Your machine must be able to handle $b$ of arbitrary length. You may assume the head begins on $L$.

The following website may be very helpful for making your machine: https://morphett.info/turing/turing.html.

Bonus: My solution (posted as an answer) uses an alphabet of $3$ (non-endpoint) letters $\{0,1,X\}$ and has $15$ internal states. Can you do better in either capacity (or prove that it is not possible to do so)? I imagine it is impossible to do this with only the letters $\{0,1\}$, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an implementation of my solution at this [link](https://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?d226b5366595f210f1fc46b5bc3baf61).

Here's the idea behind the solution:

> The main idea behind the implementation is to have the head bounce back and forth between the two sides of the string, carrying a bit from one side over to the other, dropping it off, picking up a new bit, bringing it back over to the other side, etc. I use the letter $X$ on either side of the string to demarcate where I should 'drop off' the bit being carried. Each time I drop off a bit at an $X$, I move that $X$ toward the center of the string and pick up the bit where I wrote the $X$. Once the two $X$s meet, I drop off the final bit and halt.
>
> The main technical difficulty is that the first time the head moves over from the left to the right, there is no X on the right at which to drop off the carried bit, hence in order to both place an X and drop off the value, we essentially need to pick up **two** bits from the right instead of one. This extra information increases the number of states needed (as I am using different states to 'store' the information about which bit is carried, so doubling the number of carried bits almost doubles the number of states).
>  
> At the link you can see step-by-step how my machine works which should help it be more understandable. It also contains the code with comments describing the states.